# Cannot resolve symbol xhtml file in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, xhtml

I have been trying to use IntelliJ IDEA (**v15.0.3**) to work on a Maven project (instead of Eclipse). Everything looks fine, except the code completion on xhtml files.
The IDE cannot resolve namespaces. Even when I'm adding the taglib location under `Schemas and DTDs`.

Although the namespace becomes "green", it still says `cannot resolve symbol`.

[Here is an image to show what I mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6qdu3.png)

I have tried the `Invalidate Cache` method, deleting `workspace.xml`, deleting the `.idea` folder and reimporting the project.. Nothing has worked.

Thanx for your help!

Comment: Restart the project, sometimes it works.

Comment: I did it before posting, and I just did it again, still doesn't work.

Comment: If you find something `"Invalidate Cache and restart` then click here. This will restart with new cache. This may help you.
In android studio it is in file menu.

Comment: Did tried that, didn't helped :(